# Mongo Custom serializer causing Cannot create an abstract class

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Mongo Custom serializer causing Cannot create an abstract class

Hi, I am trying to add a custom serializer to my mongo classes, and it seems like it is not working correctly.
The goal is that we have ancient events in the database, and I want to read them in a "new format" that we have.

But the error is happening with the new events. This is the structure

```
public abastract class FooBase
{
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public Guid AggregateId { get; set; }
    //Other properties
    public abstract object GetContent();
}

public class TypedFooBase<T> : FooBase
where T : class
{
    public T TypedContent { get; set; }
    //Other properties
    
    public override object GetContent()
    {
        return TypedContent;
    }
}
```

An then I created a custom serializer like the next:

```
public class BsonAncientEventSerializer<T> : SerializerBase<TypedFooBase<T>> where T : class
{
    public override TypedFooBase<T> Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var serializer = BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(typeof(ExpandoObject));
        var obj = serializer.Deserialize(context);
        string valueString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TypedFooBase<T>>(valueString, new Json.JsonAncientEventSerializer<T>())
                ?? throw new Exception("something went wrong");
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, TypedFooBase<T> value)
    {
        var bsonWriter = context.Writer;

        var fields = value.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public); 
        var propsAll = value.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public); 

        var props = new List<PropertyInfo>(); 
        foreach (var prop in propsAll) 
        { 
            if (prop.CanWrite) 
            { 
                props.Add(prop); 
            } 
        } 

        bsonWriter.WriteStartDocument(); 

        foreach (var field in fields) 
        { 
            bsonWriter.WriteName(field.Name); 
            BsonSerializer.Serialize(bsonWriter, field.FieldType, field.GetValue(value)); 
        } 
        foreach (var prop in props) 
        { 
            bsonWriter.WriteName(prop.Name); 
            BsonSerializer.Serialize(bsonWriter, prop.PropertyType, prop.GetValue(value, null)); 
        } 

         context.Writer.WriteEndDocument(); 
    }
}
```

and then I register the serializer:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(
            typeof(TypedFooBase<TestEvent>),
            new BsonAncientEventSerializer<TestEvent>()
        );
```

If I don't register the serializer, everything works fine (except the compatibility with old events).
But when I add register the serializer, the code does not work correctly;

The `serialize` works fine (the values are stored in the database correctly);

But on the read, it is not working. The code does not stop in the `Deserialize` at all.

The collection I am accessing in code is an `IMongoCollection<FooBase>`;

Then when I do `collection.Find(...).ToListAsync()`, it gives me an error of `Cannot create an abstract class`.

This is because it is trying to convert the value into a `FooBase`;

But why is it doing it? And why, when I do not register the serializer works fine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're seeing is related to the fact that you register a custom serializer for `TypedFooBase<TestEvent>`, but the collection type that is used during deserialization is `FooBase`, so the required serializer is not found.
You may try:

- Mapping the serializer to the base type:

  ```
    BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(
        typeof(FooBase),
        new BsonAncientEventSerializer<TestEvent>()
  ```

and appropriate serializer definition:

```
public class BsonAncientEventSerializer<T> : SerializerBase<FooBase> where T : class
```

- In theory the best approach is to use appropriate type for getting result like:

  ```
  var result = collection.OfType<TypedFooBase<TestEvent>>().Find("{}").ToList();
  ```

but to make it work, you need to implement [discriminator](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/) behavior that is skipped in your serialization step, because `OfType` additionally adds a `_t`(discriminator) filter that is not presented in your serialized document.

NOTE: i didn't check it, but I think you can just create a new typed (not base) collection instance (that doesn't make any server requests itself) only for Find operation: `IMongoCollection<TypedFooBase<TestEvent>>`

- Also, you may look at this [doc](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/reference/bson/mapping/schema_changes/)
- **UPDATE**: it sounds like this way:

  ```
  var result = coll.FindSync("{}", new FindOptions<FooBase, TypedFooBase<TestEvent>>()).ToList();
  ```

should also work.